# Sum with reciprocal of square central binomial $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty {\frac{1}{{{n^3}{{\left( {C_{2n}^n} \right)}^2}}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

I am trying to evaluate this sum:
$$S=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{n^3}{{\left( {C_{2n}^n} \right)}^2}}}}$$

My attempt:

$$\begin{array}{l}
S = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{n^3}{{\left( {C_{2n}^n} \right)}^2}}}}  = \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {C_{2n}^n} \right)}^2}}}} \int\limits_0^1 {{x^{n - 1}}{{\ln }^2}\left( x \right)dx = } \int\limits_0^1 {{{\ln }^2}\left( x \right)dx\left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{n - 1}}}}{{{{\left( {C_{2n}^n} \right)}^2}}}} } \right)} \\
 = \displaystyle\frac{1}{8}\int\limits_0^1 {{{\mkern 1mu} _3}{F_2}\left( {1,2,2;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{x}{{16}}} \right){{\ln }^2}\left( x \right)dx}  = \frac{1}{4}{{\mkern 1mu} _4}{F_3}\left( {1,1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{1}{{16}}} \right)
\end{array}$$
The result with hypergeometric function is generated by CAS, and I don't know how to express this result in a closed-form.

Can I ask some hints, or another approach? Thank you so much.

Edit 1: Since we have:$$\arcsin^2(x)=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2x)^{2n}}{n^2{2n\choose n}}$$ and $$\int_0^1\frac{y^{n-1}}{\sqrt{1-y}}dy=\frac{4^n}{n{2n\choose n}}$$ Then may be we can multiply and integrate, but I don't know how to get rid of $4^n$.

Comment: $$
\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\Gamma^4(n+1)}{n^3\Gamma^2(2n+1)}
$$
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{\Gamma^4(n+2)}{(n+1)^3\Gamma^2(2n+3)}
$$
$$
=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{\Gamma^4(2)2_n2_n2_n2_n}{(n+1)^3(3)_{2n}3_{2n}\Gamma^2(3)}
$$
$$
=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{2_n2_n2_n2_n}{(n+1)^3(3/2)_n(3/2)_n2_n2_n2^{4n}4}
$$
$$
=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{2_n2_n2_n2_n1_n1_n1_n}{2_n2_n2_n(3/2)_n(3/2)_n2_n2_n2^{4n}4}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{4} \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{1_n1_n1_n}{2_n(3/2)_n(3/2)_n2^{4n}}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{4}{}_4F_3(1,1,1,1 ; 3/2,3/2,2 ; \frac{1}{16})
$$